# Windows cmd-output (Java)

Tags: java

I've found this topic, but the code doesn't work for me... [Return Windows cmd text from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003144/return-windows-cmd-text-from-java/11749253)

After pressing a button I want to execute a batch-file, for testing purposes it's just the ipconfig-command.

The cmd-output should be written into a JTextFiled, but all I get is no text...

Here the code for writing it into the JTextField:

```
btnLock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {       
            String g = "";
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"ipconfig", g});
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }  
            Process p = null;
            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"ipconfig", g});
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream s = p.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
            String temp;

            try {
                while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(temp);
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    btnLock.setBounds(10, 68, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnLock);
```

So what do I do wrong?

It's my first project with cmd-input, so please don't get mad cause of silly mistakes I made. ;)

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `exec` command that just takes a String parameter. The following test code worked on my system (though I was only printing to console, not to textfield):

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try{
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig");
    InputStream s = p.getInputStream();

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
    String temp;

    while ((temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) in.close();
}
```

Also your code in the original post is also using a `System.out.println`. As far as I'm aware, you can't print to a JTextField using `System.out.println`.... You'd have to use the `setText` method.

Comment: Ok, it works fine with a non-gui-application. But if I try it with my GUI (and a JTextArea) the output is only the last line...

Comment: Well yes. It's in a while loop. You'll want to do something like `String outpt = ""; while( (temp = ...)) { outpt += temp + "\n"; } textField.setText(outpt);`

Answer (score 3):

If I run

```
 ipconfig ""
```

I get

```
** Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.**
```

You can only run from Java, commands which work on the command line.

BTW: If you are looking for errors, you need to read the error stream.

Comment: Thx, I'm new to Java, so please excuse, but what does "commands which work on the command line" mean? Why does ipconfig not work on the command line?

Comment: Explicitly, `ipconfig ""` does not work on the commandline. `ipconfig` does.

Comment: @user1318160 I suggest you try it on the command line for yourself. ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the "" , sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I would `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"ipconfig > temp.txt"});` and then just read it as a text file using a `BufferedReader`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have the whole code? I tried to do it, but I only get: Error: unrecognized or incomplete command line.

Comment: Ok, I used Roddy of the Frozen Pea's solution, works flawlessly.